# How to install Firefox3.6.15 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit OS

Tags: software-installation

Our hospital web application supports only in firefox3.6.15 version. Please help to install firefox3.6.15 in ubuntu14.04 LTS 64 bit version.

I just tried to install mozilla firefox 3.6.15 in Ubuntu.

Downloaded the firefox-3.6.15.tar.bz2

```
root@it-us-02:~/Desktop# tar xvf firefox-3.6.15.tar.bz2

root@it-us-02:~/Desktop# mv firefox /opt/firefox3.6.15

root@it-us-02:~/Desktop# ln -s /opt/firefox3.6.15/firefox /usr/bin/firefox

root@it-us-02:/opt/firefox3.6.15# ./firefox

XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox42/libxul.so: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Comment: That means the web application was designed *very* badly.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I think the issue is beacuse he's using a tar file, instead of doing "sudo apt-get install firefox-3.6.15".

Comment: @StarOS Is that package even available? In any case, any decent web app should be supporting all modern browsers.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I don't know since i'm not running Ubuntu, but it most likely exists.

Answer (score 5):

Download the deb file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/firefox-mozilla-build_3.6.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb/download)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/firefox-mozilla-build_3.6.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb/download

Install the deb file with

```
sudo dpkg -i ./firefox-mozilla-build_3.6.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

and tell IT mission critical software should at least follow the firefox ESR releases (running a browser that old on anything facing the internet should be considered a crime)

Comment: Sir, I just downloaded the deb file from above mentioned path and run the sudo dpkg -i ./firefox-mozilla-build_3.6.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb command. After completing installation firefox didn't invoke. Please help

Comment: @Sumesh What do you get when running firefox from the command line?

Comment: (Reading database ... 260704 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firefox-mozilla-build_3.6.15-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-mozilla-build (3.6.15-0ubuntu1) over (3.6.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up firefox-mozilla-build (3.6.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...

Comment: @Sumesh It seems you are posting the result from the dpkg command. I am asking for the output from running firefox in the terminal.

Comment: Also note that the build might not place the files in the regular locations, so simply running the command `firefox` might invoke the older (er, newer) version. You can try `find / -name firefox -type f -ls 2>/dev/null` to locate all files on the system named `firefox`, which hopefully should be a small enough number to locate the newly installed copy.

Comment: root@it-us-02:/usr/bin# find / -name firefox -type f -ls 2>/dev/null
    91    4 -rw-------   1 aims     aims         3939 Aug 25  2010 /media/aims/Data/Ubuntu14/Installation/Firefox/firefox-3.6.9-ins/firefox
 11341    4 -rw-------   1 aims     aims       3940 Mar  3 2011 /media/aims/Data/Ubuntu14/Installation/Firefox/firefox3.6.15/firefox
1191167    4 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root         3940 Mar  3 2011 /opt/firefox/firefox
root@it-us-02:/opt/firefox# ./firefox
./firefox-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Sir, I have one doubt. The current debian file seems to be 32 bit (i386.deb). My requirement is for 64 bit. Is there any problem?..